# Access vba block executing when it shouldn't

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have a subroutine that runs when I click a button on my form.  The problem is that no matter what happens, the error block is executed, and I can't figure out why.  I'm not very good with Access VBA, so it may be a simple error.

Here's my sub:

```
Public Sub findRecord()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs = Me.[dbo_NCL_SimmonsCodes subform1].Form.Recordset

    rs.FindFirst "NCL_ItemNum=""LSIM-" & Me.Text0 & """"

    If rs.NoMatch Then

         MsgBox "No match found.  Please try again." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "If this is a new item, please click the Add Record button to add.", vbInformation, "No Match"

    End If

On Error GoTo description_Error

    Me.lblDescription.Caption = DLookup("Description", "dbo_AL_ItemUPCs", "ItemCode ='" & Me.Text0 & "'")

Exit_FindRecord:
    Exit Sub

description_Error:

        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & vbNewLine, vbExclamation, "VBA Error " & Err.Number
        Me.lblDescription.Caption = "Error."
        Resume Exit_FindRecord

End Sub
```

Comment: And what's teh Err.Number we have when reaching the ErrHandler? Is it really zero?

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso -Yes, it is 0.

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso -Or I should say that it is 0 when it should be (When the dlookup works finds a proper match), but i shouldn't be getting the messagebox at all in those cases.

Comment: Have you tried running it in debug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually looks like a logic error.  If the FindFirst statement has no match, it the routine should exit there, instead of continuing.  I added 'Exit Sub' below that messagebox, and now I'm good.

```
Public Sub findRecord()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs = Me.[dbo_NCL_SimmonsCodes subform1].Form.Recordset

    rs.FindFirst "NCL_ItemNum=""LSIM-" & Me.Text0 & """"

        If rs.NoMatch Then
                MsgBox "No match found.  Please try again." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "If this is a new item, please click the Add Record button to add.", vbInformation, "No Match"
                Me.lblDescription.Caption = "Error - No match."
                Exit Sub      
                '^^Added^^'
        End If

On Error GoTo description_Error

            Me.lblDescription.Caption = DLookup("Description", "dbo_AL_ItemUPCs", "ItemCode ='" & Me.Text0 & "'")

Exit_FindRecord:
        Exit Sub

description_Error:
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & vbNewLine, vbExclamation, "VBA Error " & Err.Number
        Me.lblDescription.Caption = "Error."
        Resume Exit_FindRecord

End Sub
```

Comment: Good to know! It was sounding to be something related to the Caption change block...

Answer (score 1):

That's an odd behavior, indeed.

I'd suggest you to change the Error Trapping behavior in VBA from 'Break on Unhanded Errors' to 'Break on All Errors' to see if there's anything else raising errors around.

Another thing to do to check specifically where the problem is, is slicing up the code. My first suggestion would be to remove the Caption change line and rerun the sub to check if the behavior is still happening.

Besides, make sure the whole project is compiling. If not, VBA can easily present strange behaviors.

Change it and let us know what happens... I can't see anything clearly wrong with the code.